# Access last element of a TypeScript array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a notation to access the last element of an array in TypeScript? In Ruby I can say: `array[-1]`. Is there something similar?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can access the array elements by its index. The index for the last element in the array will be the length of the array-1 (as indexes are zero based).

This should work:

```
var items: String[] = ["tom", "jeff", "sam"];

alert(items[items.length-1])
```

[Here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20items%3A%20String%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%22tom%22%2C%20%22sam%22%2C%20%22joy%22%5D%3B%0A%0Aalert(items%5Bitems.length-1%5D)) is a working sample.

Comment: That doesn't feel like a "notation" to me.

Comment: I agree with Amit. So far I haven't found a 'notation.' The next best which is a little more concise but still not a notation is items.slice(-1).

Comment: Not that I really care, but if you don't feel it's a good answer, why did you mark it as such?

Comment: @pitosalas slice returns an array ... as you have already discovered : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31277569/390330 :)

Answer (score 62):

As of July 2021, browsers are starting to support the [`at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method for Arrays which allows for the following syntax:

```
const arr: number[] = [1, 2, 3];

// shows 3
alert(arr.at(-1));
```

It's not clear to me at what point TypeScript will start to support this (it's not working for me just yet) but it should be available soon I would guess.

**Edit:** This is available as of `typescript@4.5.4`

Comment: It is now! https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45512#issuecomment-1004034848

Comment: The .at method has the additional advantage of including undefined in the type should your index not be included in the array.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.6.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBFDuIAyBTKUUCcIwLwwG0ByAQSIBoYiAhIgXQG4BYAKFYHp2ZRJYoALAJaYAJqnRYAXDGiZBYAOase0OENHiMmPHESasEAgCZGrDlxV91YtFpJRps+QpgAfGAFcwIlADN5KCLK4KoCwjYSmPY6CMi2BgB0AIZQABRGAJRAA

Comment: This works for me. Defnitely my favorite option :)

Answer (score 56):

If you don't need the array afterwards, you could use

```
array.pop()
```

**But that removes the element from the array!**

The pop returns `T | undefined` so you need to take care of that in your implementation.

If you are sure there will be always a value you can use **non-null assertion operator** (`!`):

```
     var poped = array.pop()
     array.push(poped!);
```

Comment: It may also give warning as `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: Let's aim to not modify data structures if we don't have to. In general, we should strive for immutability, modifying structures just for the sake of access is ill-advised.

Answer (score 47):

Here is another way which has not yet been mentioned:

```
items.slice(-1)[0]
```

Comment: Considering this creates an almost complete copy of the array I don't believe that's the best answer. If the array is quite large, this is not a good approach performancewise.

Comment: @Loop slice(-1) does not create a copy of all array. It'll copy just the last element into new array. I do believe this is a concise solution. Best solution for when this isn't called excessively as we create a throwaway array with one element each time just to get its element. Not too problematic but unnecessary in any case.

Answer (score 15):

Here are a the options summarized together, for anyone finding this question late like me.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

// Fastest method, requires the array is in a variable
myArray[myArray.length - 1];

// Also very fast but it will remove the element from the array also, this may or may 
// not matter in your case.
myArray.pop();

// Slowest but very readable and doesn't require a variable
myArray.slice(-1)[0]
```

Comment: Is `slice` really much slower than the others? `pop` is also a function call.

Answer (score 9):

If you need this call more often it's possible to declare it globally:

```
interface Array<T> {
    last(): T | undefined;
}
if (!Array.prototype.last) {
    Array.prototype.last = function () {
        if (!this.length) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return this[this.length - 1];
    };
}
```

then you can just call

```
items.last()
```

Comment: How do I declare it, globally?

Comment: Modifying the prototype of built-ins is not advisable.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going with this one as my first contribution to stackoverflow:

```js
var items: String[] = ["tom", "jeff", "sam"];

const lastOne = [...items].pop();
```

NOTE: Unlike the use of `pop()` without the spread operator, this approach doesn't remove the last element from the original array.

Comment: Oops! This is creating a whole new copy of the array.  So the performance is almost quite terrible.

Comment: This was my first contribution to StackOverflow, I was young and naive .... Please, don't judge me!!! XD  .... and please don't throw negatives at me! ;) (In later posts I think I offered better content). Cheers!

Comment: No worries, Juan.  Don't take it personally.  It's great to have all sorts of answers on StackOverflow, so people can see why some of them might not perform as fast as the others.  At the end of the day, we all are here to learn and grow!  Keep up the good work. :)

Answer (score 2):

there are several ways you could do this.

1. By the index of the last element.

```
arr[arr.length - 1]
```

2. Use the slice function: this function returns the value in an array that's why accessing the 0'th index is required.

```
arr.slice(-1)[0]
```

3. Use the pop() function:  this method is helpful when you need to get and remove the last element of the array. element will be returned and the last element will be removed from the original array.

```
arr.pop()
```

4. Use the at() function. NOTE: This was introduced in ES22 and will not work in older versions

```
arr.at(-1)
```

You can pick any one of those methods based on your preferences.

Answer (score 2):

One line Typescript function:

```
const last = <T>(arr: T[]): T | undefined => arr.at(-1);
```

if you use old ES versions:

```
function last<T>(arr: T[]): T | undefined {
    return arr[arr.length - 1];
}
```

All fns have almost the the same perfomance. I recommend you to use `arr[arr.length - 1]` as the most native.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 6, 2];
console.log(...arr.slice(-1)); // 2
```

Comment: Is using the spread a good idea here? We only want a single element.

Comment: Note: the spread operator will only work in this case if you need to use the last value to pass directly into a function, as the spread operator maps the positions of the array to the parameters of the functions in order

Answer (score 0):

```
let arry = [A, B, C, D, E, F];
let lastElement = arry.slice(-1);

console.log(lastElement);
```

You will get the Answer as F .