# Typescript type error doesn't make sense

Tags: typescript

```
interface A
  {
    x:string; y:string
  };

var a: A[] = [];
a.push(
  {x: "a", 
   y: "b"});

a.slice(-1).x = "foo";
```

That last line gets an error I think because the result of a.slice(-1) is not of a known type, so it says "no known property x".

1. Is my diagnosis correct?
2. What's the right way to do that?

Comment: Can you please post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a.slice(-1) returns an array (the slice) even though it has only one element. An array does not have the "x" property. But each element does.

So the following does what is expected:

```
a.slice(-1)[0].x = "foo";
```

Comment: TypeScript saving ya ;)

Comment: yeah, but it could have given a more useful error message, like: value typeof "array"  does not have property "x".