# Typescript - Trying to extract elements from array. Getting last element instead

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm trying to extract all elements from an array but instead i'm getting the last element of it
This is my code:

```
// this.data contains data from a http.get
// I tried using user: [] and user: any = [];  
user: Array; // 
pass: Array;
for (const x of this.data) {
                this.user = x.username;
                this.pass = x.password;
           } // console.log(this.user); Output = lastelementfromthearray
```

Comment: Same question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277004/access-last-element-of-a-typescript-array

Comment: What does the `mc` object have to do with the content of the array? Anyway, apart from that, your problem is that you are overriding `this.user` at every iteration, which means that you'll only get the final one at the end of the loop.

Comment: @Lior Yeah but i don't want to access to certain one, i want to acces to all of them.

Comment: @bugs My bad, i updated it. So in that case what do you recommend me to do?

Comment: So, you already have an array (data), containing everything you need. There is nothing to extract. `data` is what you want: the array of username/passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have an array of some fields from objects that are contained in another array, it's:

```
this.user = this.data.map(({ username }) => username);
this.pass = this.data.map(({ password }) => password);
```

If the array is big enough or the place is performance-critical, this can be done in a single loop, preferably `for`/`while`:

```
this.user = [];
this.pass = [];

for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
  this.user.push(this.data[i].username);
  this.pass.push(this.data[i].password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are overriding `this.user` at each iteration. Since this.user is an array, what you want to do is instead pushing `x.username` to the array. the same of course applies to the other array.

```
    user = [];
    pass = [];
    for (const x of this.data) {
      this.user.push(x.username);
      this.pass.push(x.password);
    }
```

Comment: You also have to initialise the arrays, I've modified the answer

Comment: It worked but not as i expected because it saves all(username and password)  elements in this.user instead of dividing this.user(x.username) and this.pass(x.password)